# Is it possible to embed a report held on crystal server into a separate web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports

We're developing an ASP MVC web application for a company to monitor and correct incoming data from third parties, then preview a report output before being distributed to their own clients. We've made a prototype with the reports being generated as Crystal Reports through the application itself using CR for Visual Studio.

The client already has a Crystal Server for some internal reporting, we're wondering if we can hook into that so that all Crystal Reports are stored in the same place and save on duplication. We would need to expose a preview of the report in our application and then export the reports from the Crystal Server in PDF and Excel formats ready to be distributed.

Is that possible? I've found very little on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody comes back for the answer... We've managed to get this working by using the 'opendocument' url path feature and embedding it into the site using an iframe. Documentation [is here.](https://help.sap.com/doc/businessobject_product_guides_sbo41_en_sbo41_opendocument_en_pdf/4.1/en-US/sbo41_opendocument_en.pdf)